# SVN Externals in Git

Tags: git, subversion

I have a handful of projects that utilize SVN externals. How should these externals be handled in Git? For reference, these externals are shared by multiple repositories and are updated very infrequently, but typically the changes are very impactful (non-backwards compatible).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/465151/2777965

Comment: Did the link help?

Comment: @030 Yes it did, thank you! Submodules are the way to go. If you wouldn't mind answering with a brief summary, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could `git svn clone` a subversion repository and use submodules.